# Number of Excalimation mark depend on the user entry for num2

Tags: java

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

for(int counter = 0; counter<=num1;counter++)
{
    System.out.println("Hello, World" + num2 Integer.parseInt("!"));
}
```

The user will enter 2 integers. First number depends on the number of loop. Second is the number of exclamation marks would duplicate. For example if the user input `java Practice4 2 4` the output would be:

```
Hello, World!!!!
Hello, World!!!!
```

Can you help me for the second number please how can i make the exclamation mark be multiplied by number the user inputs

Comment: Thats what loops are for: [The while and do-while Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) - [The for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write another loop to create that String of exclamation marks, e.g.:

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

for(int counter = 0; counter<=num1;counter++) {
        StringBuilder exclamations = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < num2 ; i++) {
            exclamations.append("!");
        }
        System.out.println("Hello, World" + exclamations.toString());
}
```

Comment: But what is StringBuilder what does this class do?

Comment: @AbdullaAhli you can read about `StringBuilder` class [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Also, you can accept the answer as correct if it has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

for(int counter = 0; counter<=num1;counter++)
{
System.out.print("Hello, World");

for(int j=0;j<num2;j++)
System.out.print("!");

System.out.println();
}
```

This code will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your two `Strings`: `Hello World` and `!`

And in your loop, create a second loop that adds the `!` as many times as necessary.

```
String hw = "Hello World";
String excl = "!";

for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (int j = 0; j < num2; j++) {
       sb.append(excl);
   }
        System.out.println(hw + sb);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with only 1 loop:

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

for(int counter = 0; counter<=num1;counter++)
{
    System.out.println(String.format( "Hello, world" + ((num2>0) ? (" %0"+num2+"d"): ""), 0).replace(  "0", "!" ));
}
```

Even though it works it's pretty unreadable and in the long run hard to maintain.

And if you go for something even more unreadable you can use the same scheme to make it work with no loop at all.